# Help with homework

Tags: british-english

Hello I can't solve some of my homework.

"She had no time for(MW)makeup" Missing word? 
"She took(WW) a shower" Wrong Word?

I can't figure out what I did wrong in this part it sounds right to me...

Comment: Your two examples are fine for a native (AmE) English speaker. Now, as for an EFL class . . .

Comment: Your examples make perfect sense to me exactly the way they are.

Comment: Obviously, the teacher was looking for a missing verb regardless of the fact that 1) is fine but means something other than put on/apply make-up. I expect men not to get this, necessarily. Why should they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"She had no time for *applying* makeup."
"She *had* a shower."
I would say both sentences are grammatical, though perhaps a little informal regarding the tone!

Comment: It might help to know that subjects of the Queen do not normally 'take' baths nor showers. They 'have' both baths and showers. If we 'take' a bath, it counts as shoplifting!

Comment: @WS2: I wouldn't exactly say that. Brits are [more likely than Americans](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=she+had+a+shower%2Cshe+took+a+shower&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshe%20had%20a%20shower%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%20took%20a%20shower%3B%2Cc0) to ***have*** a shower, but even we still use ***took*** more often. The same applies (but not quite so strongly) with *baths*.

Comment: I don't apply my lipstick, I put it on. Dionne Warwick said better than I did, *The moment I wake up, before I put on my makeup*

Comment: WS2, you're right. British people normally *have* baths and showers. Using the word *take* in this context, would be very unusual in the UK.

Comment: @Tristan: Tristan, I'll take FF's evidence over your (and WS2's) unsupported views / preferences. It's time to realise that even British English usage (and this means what is considered acceptable) has not remained constant since the time we were in Grammar School.

Comment: @Edwin: Yes, but I admit I still have a certain fondness for usages like *"Will you take tea [, Vicar]?"*, even though it's not exactly the sort of thing a learner particularly needs to know about.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I'm no expert on the subject (obviously! :) but I think posh girls *apply* it, ordinary girls *put it on*, and "Essex" girls *slap it on*. The lowest of the low (who shall remain nameless) [put on some slap.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22put+on+some+slap%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Personally, I put on mascara, lashings of the stuff. I think the verb, apply, is mostly used in makeup artists' manuals. "I need to put on some lipstick" rolls off the tongue. Maybe it's an 80s thing.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I was just kidding. Even though I'm no expert, I'd bet my life (without checking NGrams) that you are quite correct in asserting that most people ***put on*** makeup. But then again, if they were in a rush, I'd also bet my life they'd *have no time **to** put it on*. Few people would say they *have no time **for** putting it on*, and frankly I think whoever set OP's homework is in the wrong job.

Comment: @Mari-LouA System of a Down put it quite aptly as well: "wake up, rgrwgrgwegrewrh makeup!"

Comment: Edwin, "we"? Not everyone has the opportunity to go to a grammar school. My comment was not based on perceived views or preferences. It was based on my experiences.

Comment: @Tristan But your experiences are different from mine (I see you went to a private school :-) ). I've come across 'take a shower' more frequently than 'have a shower' in the last ten years say (though the frequencies are reversed for 'take / have a bath'). (I live in Oldham.) And FF's data echoes this observation. So I'd say British people normally have baths and take showers. The statement 'Using the word take in this context would be very unusual in the UK' is far from correct, and subjectively based.

Comment: Edwin, in that case, usage must vary even within the UK. Just like experiences do.

Comment: @Tristan: I didn't go to a grammar school either (secondary modern, me). But like you, I've been speaking and hearing English all my life, in a wide range of contexts (socioeconomic, regional, age-based, etc.). Apparently *unlike* you, for many decades I've also tended to take special notice of any usages I encounter which don't match whatever I first learnt as a child. All other things being equal (which they often aren't, of course) I prefer to use *the most common form **now*** (in the context of the people I'm currently interacting with), so I like to be able to find out what that is.

Comment: I'm with Mary-Lou here. In any case, professional make-up artists may and do apply make-up. However, us common mortals: put on make-up or put make-up on regardless of our bathing habits. And this is definitely a distaff thing. Queen Elizabeth the First had a layer of make-up caked on her face and when she died, it apparently fell off like a mask. (No, I don't remember the details here at all.). In any case, she was not a bather.....none of them were.